# Is initializing empty array with high indexes expensive in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, performance

I want to save `year-month-day` in ruby by creating 3d array to make look-up O(1):

```
dates = [Date.new(2014,2,15), Date.new(2015, 8, 27), Date.new(2014, 7, 4), ...]
res = []
dates.each do |d|
    # Init year if DNE
    if res[d.year].nil?
        res[d.year] = []
    end
    # Init month if DNE
    if res[d.year][d.month].nil?
        res[d.year][d.month] = []
    end
    # Set the [year][month][day] = 1
    res[d.year][d.month][d.day] = 1
end
```

```
# Use case
def date_in_array?(date)
    !res[self.year].nil? && !res[self.year][self.month].nil? && !res[self.year][self.month][self.day].nil?
end

date_in_array?(Date.new(2014, 2, 15))
=> true

date_in_array?(Date.new(2014, 9, 21))
=> false
```

The alternative is to use a Hash to save dates, but it could get expensive in terms of memory.

So my question is, how does ruby manage array index out of range?

I want to make sure that by doing `res[2015] = []`, ruby doesn't initialize the `res[0..2014]` set and this is indeed a good way to store data in this case.

Comment: How many years do you actually have to cover?

Comment: @Stefan It's up to the user. Generally it could range from 5-10 years but there is no limit.

Comment: You can write that more compactly as `arr = dates.each_with_object([]) { |d,a| ((a[d.year] ||= [])[d.month] ||= [])[d.day]=1 }` If `dates` contains the first three dates in your example, `arr[2014][2][15] #=> 1; arr[1492] #=> nil`. Note; `arr.flatten.compact #=> [1, 1, 1]`.  (You don't want to use arrays here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make sure that by doing `res[2015] = []`, ruby doesn't initialize the `res[0..2014]` set and this is indeed a good way to store data in this case.

Nope. It does. This snippet just **rendered my system unresponsive** by eating most of the RAM. Solid proof.

```
@a = []
@a[1_000_000_000] = 1
```

How to store data depends on what values are you expecting as keys.

An array is, by definition, a large chunk of consecutive memory cells each storing a value. Constant access time is achieved because for any known index it takes one arithmetic operation (base + index) to compute a memory address of the needed cell. If keys are non-sequential then you shouldn't be using an array in the first place.

Disks are not used for array storage, only virtual RAM (that may be configured to use swap space, but don't count on it).

If keys are sequential but don't start close to 0 (i. e. 1990 and up) you can create a wrapper for a built-in array that contains an array inside and a "lower bound" that is used for computing a "real index" in that array. Implement `[]` and `[]=` and you'll get array-like access.

```
class ShiftedArray
  def initialize(lower_bound)
    @lower_bound = lower_bound
    @storage     = []
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    @storage[key - @lower_bound] = value
  end

  def [](key)
    @storage[key - @lower_bound]
  end
end
```

`ShiftedArray.new(1)` is effectively 1-indexed array.

Of course, this is far from ideal, it doesn't allow writing in values lower than the bound set at construction time. You can implement that, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

If keys are highly scattered numbers, you might be better off using a `Hash` or a search tree as data structure.

Answer (score 2):

> Is initializing empty array with high indexes expensive in Ruby?

Yes. Ruby will allocate memory for entries 0..2015 in your example. You do want hashes in this case; hash lookups (as tadman mentioned) are amortized O(1), so speed shouldn't be a concern, and the memory usage should be substantially improved over sparse arrays, as well.

By way of example (MRI 2.2.2):

```
require 'objspace'
res = []; ObjectSpace.memsize_of res                          #=> 0
res = []; res[100] = true; ObjectSpace.memsize_of res         # => 928
res = []; res[2015] = true; ObjectSpace.memsize_of res        # => 16248
res = {}; res[100] = true; ObjectSpace.memsize_of res         # => 192
res = {}; res[2015] = true; ObjectSpace.memsize_of res        # => 192
```

Comment: This actually makes it very clear. So Hash or Set is the way to go in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A Hash is likely to be far cheaper than a triply nested array structure. The overhead for any individual array is way higher than for a single Hash entry.

Don't forget Hash lookups are technically *O(1)*, constant-time, so there's no concern about performance here. There's also other options.

The super slack version of this is using Set which is like a hybrid between an Array and a Hash:

```
require 'set'
dates = Set.new([ Date.new(2014,2,15), Date.new(2015, 8, 27), Date.new(2014, 7, 4) ])

dates.include?(Date.new(2014,2,15))
# => true
dates.include?(Date.new(2014,2,5))
# => false
```

You can adapt this to a Hash where the key is a date or a string. You'll often find the simplest solution is *fast enough* though.

Comment: I am more concerned about the memory in this case when using Hash.  Can't we ignore the overhead assuming the large arrays are stored on disk?

p.s. Just looked into `set` to find out ruby sets are implemented through hashes. So set might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: sPaz, why are you concerned about memory? How many dates might you have and how many different years are in the data set?

Comment: @CarySwoveland There really isn't any limit. I might have 6 or 600 in about  about 5-10 year range depending on user input.

Comment: sPaz. That's nothing if you use a hash or set. tad, I'm not familiar with the term "super slack", but whatever it means, it probably requires a hyphen.

Comment: Yes, using a set is the way to go here. sPaz, [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F) is a handy method. Suppose `dates` is the set of dates and `d` is a `Date` object which you wish to add to the set if its not already in the set.  You can execute `dates.add?(d)`. If `d` is not in `dates`, `add?` will add it and return the new `dates` set (which evaluates `true`). If `d` is already in the set, `add?` returns `nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I mean "super slack" to mean "the least complicated thing that works but may not be the most scalable or memory efficient solution". *If* this approach proves inadequate, which it wouldn't for "hundreds" of items, it would require re-thinking. Premature optimization is the first step on the long road to disaster, though, so this is probably sufficient as-is.

Comment: Oh, I actually thought it was a typo (super-slick). :-)

Comment: @sPaz A Set can probably contain anywhere from millions to tens of millions of these without breaking a sweat. If you're going beyond that, into billions of entries, you'll need to use something more advanced. A bit-mask of all possible days? A memory mapped file? It's hard to say, as it would depend on the performance characteristics and memory footprint you need.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sometimes there's [elegance in laziness](http://9gag.com/gag/aqmGVoY/this-guy-just-won-the-laziest-human-award)!

Comment: Further to your last comment, if there are billions of different dates, they would have to span more than 2.7 million years.  Assuming this is not a geological app... Aside: I expect super-slack methods tend to be used mainly by super-slackers.